# PGSQL Query - Remove the last character if it ends with a specific one

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am looking for a solution to remove a specific character from column values if it ends with "-". In the meantime, I have to use "joins" in the PGSQL query.

For example; let's say I have a column of dates (but date type is string) like below

2022-01-30

2020-03-12-

2022-10-12-

2021-06-10

I need to trim only the last "-" characters if it ends and shouldn't touch the other values. The output should be like that;

2022-01-30

2020-03-12

2022-10-12

2021-06-10

I tried to use trim(trailing "-" from table.column) format on joins but it gives error.

My query is below;

```
SELECT 
      Resource.NAME COMPUTER_NAME, CollnToResources.remarks_en COLLECTION_REMARKS 
FROM Collection 
INNER JOIN CollnToResources ON trim(trailing '-' from Collection.COLLECTION_ID)=CollnToResources.COLLECTION_ID 
INNER JOIN Resource ON trim(trailing '-' from CollnToResources.RESOURCE_ID) = Resource.RESOURCE_ID 
WHERE Collection.COLLECTION_NAME ='OS_Installation_Date_v2' 
OR Collection.COLLECTION_NAME ='Linux_OS_Installation_Date'
```

How can I overcome this issue?
Thanks

Comment: `but it gives error` ... what is the error?

Comment: Error: function pg_catalog.rtrim(bigint, unknown) does not exist. Hint: No function matches the given name and arguement types. You might need to add explicit type casts. // Additionally, I don't want to remove the last "-" on values, I want to remove it if "-" is the last char. So, I am also not sure "trailing" will solve this issue.

Comment: What are the types of `Collection.COLLECTION_ID` and `CollnToResources.RESOURCE_ID` ?

Comment: Looks like you are running into `select trim('-' from 2020-03-12); ERROR:  function pg_catalog.btrim(integer, unknown) does not exist`. In other words a value that is not a string.

Comment: I speculate that one side of the join is already a date.

Comment: Use `rtrim(table.column, '-')` or `to_date(rtrim(table.column, '-'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')` if a convertion to type date is needed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I realized I applied it into bigint data type. After I apply the correct one, it's solved. Thanks for the correction and additional information